# SharePoint online Image item URL does not get url in target Release for Everyone

Tags: office-365, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx-webparts, pnpjs

I have tried to get image URL using rest Api and PnP js in my SPFx react solution but not get proper image URL from Api response.

Below is the code and response from the Api. Missing serverRelativeUrl and serverUrl from NewImage and TilesImage columns.

**Code:**

`const lItemsSchemaTest: any[] = await _sp.web.lists.getById(lSelectedListTitle).items();`

**Response:**

[image]

---

I have another tenant and from there I got perfect url with serverRelativeUrl and serverUrl.

**Code:**
`const lItemsSchemaTest: any[] = await _sp.web.lists.getById(lSelectedListTitle).items();`

**Response:**

[image]

[image]

**Resolution**
Change the release to Standard Release .

Thanks

Comment: Are you using [SharePoint Image Column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) in your lists?

Comment: How you set the image column values initially, using SharePoint UI or [PowerShell](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/13/add-update-image-columns-in-sharepoint-microsoft-lists-using-pnp-powershell/) or [Power Automate](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/08/add-an-image-to-sharepoint-image-columns-using-power-automate/) or [Power Apps](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2022/10/04/add-update-or-delete-images-in-sharepoint-microsoft-lists-using-power-apps/) or using any other method?

Comment: Add image using SharePoint UI. Create new item and add image

Comment: I just tried creating a new list item with Image column using SharePoint UI and it returns image URL using REST API without any issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PgB7d.png. Maybe there is some issue with your site/list. Can you try creating a new list with image column in same site and see if it works? Are you using standard release or targeted release tenant where it is not working?

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP Sharing you a mailfrom your site with access to the site with credentials

Comment: Added the release details in the question. Also have tried to change the site and the list but the issue remains the same.

Comment: @GaneshSanap-MVP, Issue identify and sorted, Works well in standard release but does not work in target release for everyone. Thanks

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Issue might be for targeted release tenants only due to recent feature release by Microsoft. Check my below answer for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried creating a new SharePoint list item with [Image column](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2020/12/06/all-you-need-to-know-about-new-image-column-type-in-sharepoint-online/) using SharePoint UI:

[image]

When I tried using SharePoint REST API call like below, it returned an image URL without any issue:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/SPConnect/_api/web/Lists/getbytitle('Logo Universe')/Items(17)?$select=Image
```

Where `Image` is the internal name of my SharePoint list image column. You can get the internal name of your SharePoint list columns by following this article: [How to find the Internal name of columns in SharePoint Online?](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2023/04/17/how-to-find-the-internal-name-of-sharepoint-columns/)

**Output**:

[image]

As discussed in the comments section above, this issue might be for targeted release tenants only due to some recent feature release by Microsoft.

Try:

1. Use Standard release tenant settings, check: [Set up the Standard or Targeted release options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/manage/release-options-in-office-365?)
2. Report this behavior of the image column in targeted release tenant to Microsoft, follow this documentation: [Get M365 Support - Online Support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/admin/get-help-support?view=o365-worldwide#online-support)

Answer (score 0):

Change the release to Standard Release from Admin Center .

[image: Select the Organization Profile , realease preferences]

Make Standard here

[image]